# Proper way to use jQuery noConflict

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling to understand the proper way to use noConflict in this context:

- My code is a widget loaded on a web page I don't control
- This web page could already contain jQuery and/or other libraries such as Prototype using $
- My widget needs its own version of jQuery (which I want to load whatever is already loaded on the page)

So far my widget works, but after it has loaded, the original web page is broken because $ points to my own version of jQuery.

Thanks for  your help !

Comment: What's the code in question? Your current question is too vague, so it cannot be answered without any more details.

Comment: What do you mean by your own version of JQuery? Loading the JQuery library twice in a page will not work. JQuery noConflict is used when two different JS libraries are loaded (e.g. JQuery and Mootools). To make sure you are using the JQuery library, you access it via noConflict().

Comment: @Imraan: You can load 2 different versions of jQuery.  `noConflict` returns the jQuery object, so you can assign it to another variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) resets the `$` to whatever it was before jQuery was loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

It can also be used to name jQuery something else (as it returns jQuery after resetting the `$` variable).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $jq = $.noConflict();
  // jQuery is now `$jq` instead of `$`
</script>
```

So what you can do is use `$` as the current jQuery, and `$jq` as your version.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="your_jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $jq = $.noConflict();
  // Your jQuery is `$jq`, and the original jQuery is `$`
</script>
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/axoxez/edit#javascript,html,live

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this code immediately after "your version of jQuery" is loaded.

```
$.noConflict();
```

If you've already over-written a previous library mapped to `$`, it won't help. But if you know what the previous library was (and it wasn't jQuery), you may be able to remap it to `$` using something like `$ = MooTools`.

The entire code would read ...

```
$.noConflict(); // leaves jQuery available using jQuery()
$ = MooTools; // maps the original library (MooTools in this example) back to $
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.noConflict exists to remove conflicts with other JavaScript libraries over the use of the `$` variable. It won't help you with jQuery version conflicts. The proper way to use it is to add a `script` tag like so, after the `script` tag that loads jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Presumably your widget isn't going to be able to do that (your question says that it doesn't have control over the web page), which means that you will have to document this behavior as a requirement of your widget. In other words, the user of your widget is going to have to call jQuery.noConflict for you.